# Ideas on grouping data handlers c++

Tags: c++

I am dealing with legacy code, and need some ideas on how best to do this.

```
struct A {
    int32_t x;
    std::string a;
    // ...

    static void handle(void * ptr);
    // lots of static methods
};

struct B {
    std::string b;
    enum{};
    // ...
    static void handle(void * ptr);
    // same list ofstatic methods
};
```

So if stuct C is added, the set of methods will be repeated.
It will be greatly appreciated if anyone could suggested a way of pulling out & grouping these methods, for reuse.

Comment: using ctrl+k got the above bad view.

Comment: you can use three backticks to format a block of code. check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Are the structures *related*? Can they be though of as *siblings*? Then consider inheritance. Even if the structures are not related, inheritance could be a quick and easy (but maybe not correct, design-wise) workaround.

Comment: Which is the problem that classes shared same "interface". Are implementation also the same?

Comment: As the structs are related, I suppose their implementation too. Do they really need to be static? My guess is that they share come code, so it would be better for them to not be static, and have them inherit a common abstract ancestor

Comment: What worries me most is the static handle function (instead of a non-static virtual one).. But that can be because you don't show how the static functions are used. I would expect the structs to be all derived from the same abstract baseclass

Comment: I think a little more context would help make it clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: The structs are all unrelated, but all of them have the same static methods, same implementation. I am just trying to clean up here, make it more compact, if possible.

Comment: *"same static methods, same implementation"* So just make one version of them as free functions?